What is causing LuaLS to give this bogus cast-local-type warning?
Being fairly new to the wonderful language of lua, I still don't fully
understand how all the bits and pieces fit together in the lua eco-system.
If editing the following perfectly valid code:
require "luarocks.loader"
local serpent = require "serpent"

local deser = {} -- This line produces the linter warning.
-- local deser -- If skipping the table, it goes away.
local data = { foo = "bar" }

local ser = serpent.dump(data)
_, deser = serpent.load(ser)
for k, v in pairs(deser) do
   print(k, v)
end

The following linter warning occur on line 9:

[Lua Diagnostics.] This variable is defined as type table. Cannot convert its type to string|unknown.

string cannot match table
Type string cannot match table


As visible from the comment on line 5, it is easy to silence the warning. Still, it would be interesting to better understand where it is coming from.
The function signature for serpent.load() has no type information. So my guess is that the language-server makes stuff up, by making incorrect assumptions. Is that a fair description of what is happening?
The language-server is in my case v3.9.3 of LuaLS. It does document e.g. what cast-local-type means, but I fail at finding how it comes to the conclusion that the lint should be applicable. Is it doing so by itself, or relying on a linter tool or library which could be used independently of the language-server?
How can one best deal with this kind of issues in the lua world? Introducing ambiguity, by separating declaration and assignment, was my work-around this time? Would the only better approach be the costly one of to trying to contribute type-hinting to all rocks one use?
For fully unknown API:s, like in q77429985, a suggestion is to create Definition Files. It appears those would conflict with the actual implementation, making that a problematic path to take when the real code is available for LuaLS?
